# read /etc/named.conf in shell script and get domains

Tags: shell, dns, cgi-bin, named

i need to read etc/named.conf file , and get the domains 
i want just the domains , and Order the domains line up line

```
zone "example.org" {
type master;
file "/var/named/example.org.db";
};


zone "example.com" {
type master;
file "/var/named/example.com.db";
};

};
```

i want the output like :

```
example.org
example.com
```

and i want to add this domains in www.who.is in a cgi-bin script
and the output like :

```
example.org : www.who.is/example.org
example.com : www.who.is/example.com
```

i wait you

thanks to you and thanks to all users and thanks for stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the "zone" lines start in the format you posted, then this would give the desired output:

```
grep '^zone' /etc/named.conf | cut -d'"' -f2
```

Comment: yes that is good thanks ,, please can you Explains the command grep '^zone' /etc/named.conf | cut -d'"' -f2

Comment: and how can i add the domains to www.who.is in a cgi script 
like 
www.who.is/example.com   .    www.who.is/example.org 

????????? 

thanks very much

Comment: Are you wanting to run a whois lookup on every domain name in your named.conf file? If you're on a Linux system, you should be able to run a `whois` utility locally. Then if you want to save all the whois lookups to files, you can do something like:
`grep '^zone' /etc/named.conf | cut -d'"' -f2 | while read l; do (whois $l > /tmp/$l.whois.txt); sleep 5; done`
(Note: the "sleep 5" waits 5 seconds in between queries; this is important because if you query the same whois server too quickly, it will block you for a while.)

Comment: And to explain the various commands I used:
`grep '^zone' /etc/named.conf` looks for lines in /etc/named.conf where the word "zone" is at the beginning of the line. To see how this works, look up documentation or tutorials for grep and regular expressions.
`| cut -d'"' -f2`: the pipe (|) sends the output from grep (which will be lines like `zone "example.com" {`) to the `cut` command. `-d'"' -f2` means "split the text at `"` characters, giving 3 sections, and give me the second section only (example.com)".
`| while read l ...`: look up loops in bash or sh, and output redirection.

Comment: thanks for explain and for help thanks very much 

and i mean i need to see whois for all sites on server from who.is
If you want to add any thing
Not necessarily be whois 

if i want to add "hello" after all domains who iget from named.conf like

example.com : hello
example.org : hello

etc .................
i wait you and thanks

Comment: Something like this would do that:

`grep '^zone' /etc/named.conf | cut -d'"' -f2 | while read l; do echo "$l : hello"; done`

or for the output in your question:

`grep '^zone' /etc/named.conf | cut -d'"' -f2 | while read l; do echo "$l : www.who.is/$l"; done`